# Blob play video while downloading

Tags: javascript, blob

i have a JavaScript that download file using range and while downloading ranges / parts i need method to make the video playing while downloading from the server . now the blob can't be updated after created . and creating new blob every time make the player keep jumping and will stop after all data downloaded . so how i can make my player run smooth like YouTube player

```
let test_url = "http://localhost/JsPlayer/file.mp4";
var byteNumbers = [];
window.addEventListener("load", function () {init();},false);
function init() {
  let player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  var typedArray = GetMovData(player,0,250 * 1024);
}
function GetMovData(player,start,end) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var lenght = parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range").split("/")[1]);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      var byteCharacters = atob(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1));
      for (var i = start ; i < end; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i - start);
      }
      if (end <  lenght){
        let max = end + 250 * 1024;
        if (max > lenght) {
          max = lenght;
        }
        // loop just for testing will change later
        GetMovData(player,end,max)
      }else{
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'video/ogg'});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        player.src = url;
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);

  };
  xhr.open('GET', test_url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + start + "-" + end);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: That's quite unclear what you are trying to do and for which purposes, but what YT does use is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Comment: yes after i posted this i i found that YouTube use Media Source . that was in the Base.js file of YouTube  . but now i have other problem that the media source , aloe play after the file fully downloaded  . can you help me with that ? .